# Ballistic Pendulum Demo Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I have a question about the following problem:

> [image]

I got the solution $v=\frac{M+m}{m} \sqrt{2gh}$.

But my real question is in the following picture:

> [image]

In the above slide, how can you derive the solution $v=(\frac{M+m}{m})d\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}$ and thus, $v=3d$?

Also, it seems that $v=3d$ is not correct since their unit is not matching... Can somebody explain this???

Comment: Seems like sloppy notation to me.

Comment: Hi Yk26. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Ok I adjusted the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation in the green box has the correct dimensions, but you are correct, the two sides of the equation in the blue box must have the same dimensions too (and should probably be cm/s in the example shown, but as we can't see what M/m is or what units anything else has been given in, the whole thing is baffling.

Using a binomial expansion when $d \ll L$:
$$ H = L - (L^2 - d^2)^{1/2} = L - L(1 - d^2/L^2)^{1/2} \simeq L (1 - (1 - d^2/2L^2)) = d^2/2L$$

I would then use that in your original expression

$$ v = (1+ M/m) \sqrt{2gH} = (1+M/m) \sqrt{2g d^2/2L} = (1+M/m)d\sqrt{g/L}$$

Comment: Can you explain more explicitly about $L - L(1 - d^2/L^2)^{1/2} \simeq L (1 - (1 - d^2/2L^2))$ ??

Comment: Is it because $(1-d^2/2L^2)^2=1-d^2/L^2+d^4/L^4\simeq1-d^2/L^2$ ??

Comment: Well, that is certainly true, but doesn't help with the problem! The binomial expansion of $(1 + x)^n$ is $1 + nx + n(n-1)x^2/2! + n(n-1)(n-2)x^3/3! + $... where if $x \ll 1$, then each term gets smaller and smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Units of measurements and conversion factors can be included in a numeric constant. When doing this it is necessary to specify the units of each quantity in the expression and it is mandatory to use that units.

This may look confusing, but if you master the technique you can write very simple formulae fixing a number of parameters and conversion factors into a single constant. Applying these formulae is then faster and less error prone.

Let's have a look at this specific case:

$$ v = \left[(1+M/m)\sqrt{g/L}\right] d = K d$$

The SI unit of $K$ is 1/s. So if you enter $d$ in cm, you get $v$ in cm/s, then you may need to convert it in mph multiplying by $0.0224~$mph$~$s/cm. If you include this conversion factor in $K$ its unit becomes mph/cm and the formula does the additional conversion automatically.

The fact that $K$ is such a nice and simple number depends on an accurate choice of the two masses and of $L$.

Comment: So, do you mean that $K=(1+M/m)\sqrt{g/L}\times 0.0224$ ? If so, can you explain further more why then $K=3$, even though we don't know $M, m,$ and $L$ ?

Comment: No, I don't think that can be explained...

Comment: @Yk26 the system is underdetermined (1 equation, 3 unknowns) so I cannot tell you exactly why $K=3$. However I think that those slides describe an experimental setup and I believe that the person who did it, piked up wisely the three parameters to get a simple number to ease the computation. Reasonable numbers that give you $K=3$ may be for instance: $M=2~$kg, $m=50~$g, $L=0.9~$m, but I'm just guessing, they could be whatever.